# How to convert dictionary with multiple values to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, lambda, jupyter-notebook

I have a dictionary that consists of 10 keys and each key has 1000 values. I want to convert it to dataframe in which each row (key) has 1000 columns (values) so I did this:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame([my_Dictionary], columns=my_Dictionary.keys())
```

but in the output here, it puts all the 1000 values in one column

[image]

What I want is that for each key there will be 1000 columns instead of putting all the 1000 values in one column

Answer (score 0):

you are passinga n array of a dictoionarty , just pass the dictionary itself to pandas :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_Dictionary)
```

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: @alimohammed then provide some sample data